# Pyspark "An error occurred while calling o255.showString"

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, text-comparison

I am trying to find similarity between two texts by comparing them. For this, I can calculate the tf-idf values of both texts and get them as RDD correctly. However, when I try to see the cosine similarity between them after I calculate it and print it to the dataframe, I get an error.
Here is my code:

```
conf = ps.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "10g"),
                              ("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "true"),
                              ("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")])

sc = ps.SparkContext("local[8]", conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
print("Just created a SparkContext")

df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('bbcclear.csv')
df2 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('yenisafakcategorypredict.csv')

df1 = df1.select(col("_c0"), col("News Data"))

regex_tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(gaps=False, pattern="\w+", inputCol="News Data", outputCol="tokens")
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="tokens", outputCol="tf")
idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="idf")
tf_idf_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regex_tokenizer, count_vectorizer, idf])
df1 = tf_idf_pipeline.fit(df2).transform(df1).drop("News Data", "tokens", "tf")
df1 = df1.crossJoin(df1.withColumnRenamed("idf", "idf2"))

columns = ["YS_ID","YS_IDF","BBC_ID","BBC_IDF"]
df1 = df1.toDF(*columns)

print(df1.show())

from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df1 = df1.withColumn("ID", monotonically_increasing_id())
df1 = df1.select(col("ID"),col("YS_ID"),col("YS_IDF"),col("BBC_IDF"))
df1 = df1.dropna()
print(df1.show())

@F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def cos_sim(u, v):
  return float(u.dot(v) / (u.norm(2) * v.norm(2)))

df1 = df1.withColumn("cos_sim", cos_sim(F.col("YS_IDF"), F.col("BBC_IDF")))
df1.printSchema()
df1 = df1.dropna()
print(df1.show())
```

For example, the final dataframe before the error.

```
+---+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
| ID|YS_ID|              YS_IDF|             BBC_IDF|
+---+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
|  1|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
|  2|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
|  3|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
|  4|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
|  5|    0|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|(8278,[0,1,2,3,4,...|
```

I can see the result of the function called printSchema correctly.

```
root
 |-- ID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- YS_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- YS_IDF: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- BBC_IDF: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- cos_sim: float (nullable = true)
```

When I try to see the function with the "show" function, I get the error I mentioned.

All Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Onee-Sama\PycharmProjects\pythonProject23\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(df1.show())
  File "C:\Users\Onee-Sama\Desktop\pythonProject23\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 606, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\Users\Onee-Sama\Desktop\pythonProject23\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\Onee-Sama\Desktop\pythonProject23\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Onee-Sama\Desktop\pythonProject23\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o256.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 20) (DESKTOP-PBJ7RJA executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2863)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3084)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:327)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)
```

Comment: `df.show()` does not return anything. Call it as `df.show()` not as `print(df.show())`.

Comment: There will be more to the error. There will a nested stacktrace. What do you see at the last stacktrace?

Comment: If your dataset is too large, then the cosine similarity you are trying can take time to process. Try it on limited dataset first like top 100 rows. Also while printing, just print some top rows like `df.limit(10).show()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I'm getting a very long error, I thought I'd take the part that seems logical to avoid trouble. As you said, when I delete the print part, I get the same error with "o254" instead of "o255.showString".
Here is the end of the error:
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)
I'll try with smaller dataset. Thank you so much...

Comment: I get the same error with a smaller dataset.

Comment: please post as much of the traceback as possible

Comment: I edited the first post. Can you check?